# Get numbers for the lottery

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As part of learning Lisp I'm currently trying to write a function that helps me fill out my lottery ticket. I want that function to return

- a list
- of six numbers,
- where each number is between 1 and 49,
- without duplicate numbers,
- and being the list ordered in an ascending way.

So far, I'm done with four of the five requirements. This is my current code:

```
(defun lottery ()
  (sort (loop repeat 6 collect (1+ (random 49))) #'<))
```

When I run this function I get something such as:

```
(lottery)
;; => (3 10 23 29 41 43)
```

Basically, everything's fine - except that sometimes I have the very same number twice within the list. And here it starts to get puzzling. My problem is that I'm not too sure on how to solve this in a Lisp way. There are multiple options I can think of:

- Run `remove-duplicates` on the result, then use `length` to check whether the list has less than six elements, and if so, run `lottery` a second time, `append` it to the first result, use `subseq`to only get the first six elements, and repeat. This works, but is not very elegant, especially as it involves sorting & co. multiple times.
- Start with an empty list, create a single random number using `(1+ (random 49))`, and call `pushnew`. Now call `lottery` recursively with the list until `length` returns six. I like this approach way more, but I'm still not too convinced, as this way I'd need two functions: An outer one, `lottery`, and an inner one, that is called recursively and handles the list as parameter.
- Start with a hash-table, use the numbers from 1 to 49 as keys, and set the keys' value to `nil`. Then, inside a loop, get a random number between 1 and 49, and change the value of the appropriate key to `t`. Return once six elements of the hash-table have `t` as value. IMHO this is the worst approach so far, as it wastes memory quite a lot and doesn't scale well.

What do you think of those options, and are there other ways of implementing this? How would an advanced Lisp developer solve this?

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of all the numbers from 1 to 49, shuffle, take 6, sort.

```
=> (sort (take 6 (shuffle (range 1 50))))
; (8 14 16 23 34 39)
```

#### Addition by original poster:

Just to show the final implementation, I'm adding it here:

```
(defun shuffle (list)
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (loop repeat len
      do
        (rotatef
          (nth (random len) list)
          (nth (random len) list))
      finally
        (return list))))

(defun lottery ()
  (sort (subseq (shuffle (loop for i from 1 to 49 collect i)) 0 6) #'<))

(lottery)
;; => (5 6 17 21 35 37)
```

Comment: Sometimes you miss the forest for the trees. Thanks :-)!

Comment: Note that using a vector will be more efficient.

Comment: I'll keep that in my mind. *Land of Lisp* doesn't deal with vectors, AFAICS, but I will have finished reading it soon (I think, tomorrow?). *Practical Common Lisp* and *Let over Lambda* are already waiting, and I guess in them I'll learn about vectors :-). Apart from that, you're definitely right, and if it was about real-world, I guess that at the moment I'd choose an array (and most probably will do it again using an array, just for fun :-)).

Comment: Sorry, but that shuffle doesn't look right to me.  Switching two random elements _length_ times will leave too many elements at their original place.  The loop should be something like `(loop :for i :downfrom (1- (length list)) :downto 1 :do (rotatef (nth i list) (nth (random i) list)))`.

Comment: @GoloRoden, I would recommend *On Lisp* after *Practical Common Lisp*. *Let Over Lambda* is based on *On Lisp*. It is interesting but  somewhat optional book.

Comment: @Mark: "On Lisp" is really hard to get (at least in Germany). Amazon's prices start at > 300 Euro.

Comment: @Golo, *On Lisp* is available on Paul Graham's [personal site](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html). Or I guess you like reading good old paper books? Anyway book is superb.

Comment: @GoloRoden That should be `(random (+ i 1))` instead of `(random i)` in Svante's comment -- as is it will leave too few elements in their original place.

Answer (score 0):

Using an accumulator fed by recursion:

```
(defun lottery ()
  (setf grid (loop for i from 1 to 49 collect i))
  (labels ((choose (source num)
    (if (or (null source) (zerop num))
      nil
      (let ((elem (nth (random (length source)) source)))
        (cons elem (choose (remove elem source) (1- num)))))))
    (sort (choose grid 6) #'<)))
```

The lottery function is first generating a list of numbers put into the `grid` variable. Then we define an internal `choose` local function. This function gets one random number in the list it is provided inside the interface and calls itself on the list minus the chosen element. The last step is to sort the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun lotto ()
  (labels ((lot (acc)  
             (if (= 6 (length acc)) 
                 acc 
                (lot (adjoin (1+ (random 49)) acc)))))
    (sort (lot nil) #'<)))
```

Comment: How about adding some explanation / comments / ... ?