# loop keyword immediately after finally

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I had asked how to [Get numbers for the lottery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109692/get-numbers-for-the-lottery) I was given the hint to create a function that shuffles a list. So I tried to do so, and I even got it working.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
(defun shuffle (list)
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (loop repeat len
      do
        (rotatef
          (nth (random len) list)
          (nth (random len) list))
      finally
        return list)))
```

Good news is that it works:

```
(shuffle '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; => (3 1 4 2 6 5)
```

Bad news is that I get an error message:

> WARNING: LOOP: loop keyword immediately after FINALLY: permitted by CLtL2, forbidden by ANSI CL.

Unfortunately I don't understand it. Why does it tell me that `loop` immediately appears after `finally`? And, what's wrong with the code that actually causes this?

Is there a better way to formulate this?

Comment: Bear in mind that this function, as written, will end up in a fairly uneven distribution of your lottery numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> WARNING: LOOP: loop keyword immediately after FINALLY: permitted by CLtL2, forbidden by ANSI CL.

This means that `RETURN` is a *loop keyword*, which is not allowed after `finally`, according to the ANSI CL standard.

If we want to return from the `LOOP`, we need to use the `return` macro:

```
(loop ...
      finally (return list))
```

It's actually a common mistake. `finally return <expr>` is no longer allowed since the ANSI CL standard. That's also a reason not to use CLtL2 (Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition) as a reference. The [CL Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/index.htm) is the better reference.