# Programming a lotto in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How would I go about coding a lotto in Lisp where the user randomly generates 6 numbers (non repetitive) between 1- 45, then input their own selection of lotto numbers to see if they match, and then tell them if they've won or not ?

```
(defun shuffle (list)
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (loop repeat len
          do (rotatef (nth (random len) list)
                      (nth (random len) list))
          finally (return list)))) 

(defun lottery ()
  (sort (subseq (shuffle (loop for i from 1 to 49 collect i))
                0 6)
        #'<))

(lottery)
```

(The code was actually taken from other authors from this question: [Get numbers for the lottery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109692/get-numbers-for-the-lottery))

This outputs the random numbers I need but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the user input of 6 numbers and comparing them to these numbers to see if they have 'won'.

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your post. You can get code in `code markdown` by indenting it by 4 spaces, as @Carcigenicate points out. You may want to add some more formatting to the code - just make sure every line of code is indented by 4 spaces. Good luck!

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What would the algorithm be as pseudo code?

Comment: I'm completely at a loss as to where to start, that's my major problem. I cant even figure out how to get a user inputted list.

Comment: Maybe also of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109692/get-numbers-for-the-lottery

Comment: Stackoverflow is best for programming problems and specific questions, not so much for learning the basics of a programming language. Here is a free and excellent introductory book for learning basic Lisp: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Looks like you took the code from another question.

Comment: Looks like you took code from another question's answer, failed to read the comments in which the flawed shuffle was corrected, and wrapped it into a trivial "how to write a program with this" question.

Comment: I didn't get the code from here myself, a friends gave it to me. im just looking for help, not trying to cause any upset :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with getting `n` non repeating random numbers.

```
(defun get-n-rand (n)
  (loop :for i = (adjoin (1+ (random 44)) i)
        :when (= (length i) n) :return i))
```

Now if we want 6 of them is simple enough to write `(get-n-rand 6)`

Next we want to check if every member of one list can be found in another.

```
(defun check-user-guess (guess-list actual-list)
  (equal (sort guess-list #'<) (sort actual-list #'<)))
```

Hopefully this covers the core logic. Input I will leave for now as it was covered in the other answer.

Comment: Having trouble actually running The "check user guess" how do i call it properly ?

(check-user-guess 1 2) or something along those lines ?

Comment: `(check-user-guess '(1 2 3 4) '(3 2 4 1))` gives `T` so you could have `(check-user-guess (get-n-rand 6) (get-users-guesses))` .. assuming that get-user-guesses returns a list of the numbers the user picked

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the input this should be a (unsafe) solution:

```
(defun play-lotto (&aux list)
  (dotimes (i 6)
    (loop
       (princ "Write a Integer between 0 and 50: ")
       (let ((number (read)))
         (if (and (integerp number) (< 0 number 50))
             (if (member number list)
                 (progn 
                   (princ "You can only choose a number once")
                   (terpri))
                 (progn
                   (push number list)
                   (return)))
             (progn
               (princ "Not a Integer between 0 and 50")
               (terpri))))))
  (if (equal (sort list #'<) (lottery))
      (princ "You won!")
      (princ "You lost...")))
```